# Writing a telnet client

Tags: python, c, telnet

HI,

I have a device that exposes a telnet interface which you can log into using a username and password and then manipulate the working of the device.

I have to write a C program that hides the telnet aspect from the client and instead provides an interface for the user to control the device.

What would be a good way to proceed. I tried writing a simple socket program but it stops at the login prompt. My guess is that i am not following the TCP protocol.

Has anyone attempted this, is there an opensource library out there to do this?

Thanks

Addition:
Eventually i wish to expose it through a web api/webservice. The platform is linux.

Comment: Will this program run on Windows? Linux? If windows, you could use winsock. On Linux you could surely use something equivalent.

Comment: Related question: "Using telnet in a C Program" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202859/using-telnet-in-a-c-program

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If Python is an option you could use [telnetlib](http://docs.python.org/library/telnetlib.html).

[Code example](http://docs.python.org/library/telnetlib.html#telnet-example):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib

HOST = "localhost"
user = raw_input("Enter your remote account: ")
password = getpass.getpass()

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

tn.read_until("login: ")
tn.write(user + "\n")
if password:
    tn.read_until("Password: ")
    tn.write(password + "\n")

tn.write("ls\n")
tn.write("exit\n")

print tn.read_all()
```

Comment: At the moment this seems to be the most convenient way forward.
I tired a a quick script by reading the online documentation and it works!
Now all i have to do is learn python which doesnt seem that hard!
I wonder if i can communicated between python and other C programs maybe?

Answer (score 4):

telnet's protocol is pretty straightforward... you just create a TCP connection, and send and receive ASCII data.  That's pretty much it.

So all you really need to do is create a program that connects via TCP, then reads characters from the TCP socket and parses it to update the GUI, and/or writes characters to the socket in response to the user manipulating controls in the GUI.

How you would implement that depends a lot on what software you are using to construct your interface.  On the TCP side, a simple event loop around select() would be sufficient.

Comment: True, i tried some but was running into problems. So i was hoping to find a pre-built library.

Comment: wrong, the real telnet protocol is way more complicated (teerminal type, option negociation, etc... see [RFC 854](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854.txt)). but the vast majority of poorly implemented telnet clients are simple ASCII socket.

Comment: Good point; I don't think that MAC needs to worry about those wrinkles for his purpose, however.

Answer (score 3):

While telnet is almost just a socket tied to a terminal it's not quite.  I believe that there can be some control characters that get passed shortly after the connection is made.  If your device is sending some unexpected control data then it may be confusing your program.
If you haven't already, go download wireshark (or tshark or tcpdump) and monitor your connection.  Wireshark (formerly ethereal) is cross platform and pretty easy to use for simple stuff.  Filter with tcp.port == 23

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202859/using-telnet-in-a-c-program) might be useful reading for you.

Answer (score 2):

Download [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) source code. Examine TELNET.C, the Telnet backend for Putty.

Comment: Studying Putty would be like reading the technical specifications for an internal combustion engine in effort to understand how to drive. What MAC needs is a simple example of sockets and the Telnet protocol.

Comment: I would rather say Putty is THE **SSH** client **for Windows**.

Answer (score 2):

I really find [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) a good introduction to network programming in C.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the application is trivial, a better starting point would be to figure out how you're going to create the GUI. This is a bigger question and will have more impact on your project than how exactly you telnet into the device. You mention C at first, but then start talking about Python, which makes me believe you are relatively flexible in the matter.

Once you are set on a language/platform, then look for a telnet library -- you should find something reasonable already implemented.

Comment: That is a reasonable assessment!
The application has to have two parts, one is a central server that will actually be doing all the controlling and an iPhone based UI application that users will use to make changes.

Personally I am experienced with microsoft technologies, but i have to do this using free/opensource technologies. Hence i am at somewhat of a loss as to where to begin.

I need to expose this api in a manner that can be consumed by a iphone application. In my mind that is something like a webservice. I am still not sure how i go about making one without .net =)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the source code [here](http://www.1cplusplusstreet.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=1002&lngWId=3). It has helped me out *a lot* in understanding Telnet protocol.

Answer (score 0):

See options in your telnet client: on an arbitrary listening socket and hit `escape]` to enter the client.

```
telnet> help
telnet> set ?
```