# writing a Telnet server and Telnet client in C

Tags: c, telnet

I have  selected an project for writing a Telnet server and Telnet client code in C.
i am learning C programming.

Has anyone attempted this.Please tell me how to proceed and materials to be refer.
sorry for asking source code.I am not getting how to start.So please refer me the material,so i can try

the platform i am using is ubuntu server

Thanks

Comment: So, you've got a homework to do and ask us to give you the source so you don't have to do it any more ? :-) That's not how StackOverflow works. We glady help you with specific problems, but not with *"I need to do X, please do it for me."* So, what real problems do you have with this assignment ?

Comment: Telnet servers and Telnet clients are in no way new.  Try searching google for "telnet server code" and "telnet client code"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a ton of telnet client/server implementations written on C out there. Google can easily find it for you. For instance, try searching for: `telnet.c`

Also, take a look at this thread for information on telnet servers:

[Using telnet in a C Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202859/using-telnet-in-a-c-program)

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia has [an article on the protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet) including references to the various relevant RFCs. So I would suggest starting there, and write a server and client :) If you have specific issues either with interpreting the documentation or writing the code, then post a question, but as DarkDust says, "please do my assignment for me" questions aren't usually well-received here.

Comment: SOrry i really tried but i was not getting from where to start so i was asking for programms or articles for reference.