# Telnet Iphone Development

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, telnet

I wish to create an **iphone app** the would send strings via telnet to a device im working on. Are there any telnet libraries where i could start looking at some code.

-Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, there are a number of approaches depending upon the language you want to use (C, C++, Obj-C...). Here are some previous questions that should get you on your way:

[iPhone socket program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083017/iphone-socket-program)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349346/telnet-library-for-c

[Using telnet in a C Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202859/using-telnet-in-a-c-program)

Comment: Thanks for first link. At first i didnt think thats what i needed but after some playing around I got it work. Thank you =)! .... Now for the next part ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444253/iphone-network-camera-feed