# iPhone Network Camera Feed

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, sdk, camera

I plan on mounting a Wireless Network Camera on my robot http://mydlink.dlink.com/DCS930L . DLink has an iPhone app to see live video however I want to integrate the video with my iPhone remote controller I made.

1. Is it possible to get that video feed into my own app?
2. Where should i start looking..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this was posted some time ago, but the easiest way to integrate a network camera feed into your own application is via UIWebView.  Then connect to the camera via IP address followed by /video/mjpg.cgi.