# How to handle the Telnet session with Telnet server

Tags: c, linux

I am using Telnet client from busy-box.I need to create a session with telnet server but session need to be created from c code for particular condition, once the session is created there will be some exchange of data.Once the user presses a particular key then that session should be exit and it should return back to the c code.

please can you help me in that......well i thought of using system("telnet") command from C code but i am not able to control the session.

Comment: There is a very informative thread about this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202859/using-telnet-in-a-c-program

Comment: (Too tired for real answer. Sorry.) I can think of two possibilities: extend the `telnet(1)` source code to do what you need to do, or drive a virtual pty, handing off control to the user when appropriate, and using a driver when appropriate. Details on the virtual pty approach are in [APUE2nd Edition](http://www.apuebook.com/index.html), directory `pty` from the book's source code. (The actual book has all the explanatory text, but the program's source code is small, beautiful, and available for study. :)

Comment: well if i get how to control session between telnet client and server will be good help....i went through your links but i didnt get wat i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to read from the session, then I suggest the [**popen()**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/popen.html) approach.

If you need to write and read, [it's going to be tricky](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2007-10/msg00189.html).

Comment: I usually use telnet (ip address/hostname) in windows to access to a server.
and type in username and password at prompt screen.

anyone can show me how to bind the username and password together with the ip/hostname?